# grails test-app unit test class not finding latest version of class under test (cannot find symbol)

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Grails project that I created using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite version 3.0.0M3 running on Windows 7 with JDK 1.7.  The Grails version is 2.0.4.

There is a unit test class that was running fine until I refactored the class under test by changing method names and by adding new methods. The class under test resides in a package under src/java. The unit test class was updated to reflect the refactoring changes, but now when grails test-app is executed, the unit test reports compilation errors stating that it "cannot find symbol"  All of these errors pertain to either the renamed methods or the new methods that I added.  Note that the Tool Suite does not display any error markers within the project explorer pane.

I have run grails clean both from the command line and from within the Tool Suite, as well as the Tool Suite project->clean command.  My BuildConfig.groovy has the correct directory set for grails.project.class.dir, and I verified that the class file within that location is being updated after a compile.  Here is one of the error messages that is reported

> XMLUtilTest.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>  Package pkg = u.unmarshalPackage(packageRefXml);
>                 ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   method unmarshalPackage(String)
>    location: variable u of type XMLUtil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Run refresh dependencies on your project.  (Alt+G R while selecting the project) Run your tests again.  Working?
2. try running test-app on the command line.  Does it work?
3. You can also try right-clicking on the tests Run As -> JUnit test

My guess is that grails inside of STS is using some of the old classes.  The Eclipse project will use `target-eclipse/classes` for its output folder, but Grails by default will use `target/classes` for its output folder.

I'd do a grep on the command line inside of your project for files called `XMLUtil*.class` and you might find where the duplicates lie.

Comment: Items 1 and 2 did not work, but item 3 did. Your suggestion to use grep solved my problem.  Yesterday, I had been using the Win 7 search, and it found all the class files nicely, and I cleaned those up by deleting target/classes and target-eclipse/classes.  Per your suggestion, I pulled out the trusty cygwin grep, and it found the offending class in an old jar that was in my lib directory.  I killed that jar and the tests now run.

Comment: Nice.  I wouldn't have expected that.  :)